# Someone told me elephants can be mean to each other. Are they?

Tags: biology, zoology

I was told that elephant in a herd can be mean to each other. Are elephants known to be mean to each other?

Comment: I don't think there is a notable claim here.

Comment: What is the definition of "mean"? Seems kind of subjective

Answer (score 2):

[yes](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/04/150419-ngbooktalk-elephant-behavior-rituals-animals-africa/), like most social animals.